# Drop unused levels in lattice plot

Tags: r, panel, lattice, levels

I have lattice plot (xyplot), and want to create panels for each level of combination of two factors. Some of the levels (created by fac1 * fac2) are empty, I am trying to drop the empty levels not to be plotted. Neither of the codes below work.

```
xyplot(Y~X | fac1 * fac2, data=dat,
drop.unused.levels = lattice.getOption("drop.unused.levels"))
```

or

```
xyplot(Y~X | fac1 * fac2, data=dat,
drop.unused.levels = T))
```

Apart from obvious solution of creating another column in the data with just used levels, or using ggplot, is there a way to solve the issue in the xyplot function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `xyplot(Y~X | fac1 : fac2, data=dat)`. (Btw., I would not recommend using lattice for plotting unless you are dealing with legacy code.)

Comment: Thanks. That is great. Also, yes, I have a large amount of legacy codes that use xyplot and translating them to ggplot is a future task that will take time and lots of hours. Thanks for the help.